# Sci-Fi Novel with Flaming Skull on Cover

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

There's this book I'm trying to remember but can't seem to find. It was a sci-fi novel I saw in a store maybe 5 to 10 years ago. It has what looks like a flaming monster skull very prominently on the cover. I found it again online and it was part of a series. I think the book I'm thinking of, or at least one book in the series, had a name that was a compound word starting with "Necro".

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything about the plot or setting of the book, or any of the characters?

Comment: Back in the '70s, Ballantine Books reissued a bunch of Lovecraft fiction with skull-themed covers. Could it have been one of those?

Comment: Check Brian Lumley's "Necroscope" series covers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you, Stanley Webb. That was it. ***[Necroscope: The Touch](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60834.Necroscope)*** (2006) by Brian Lumley was exactly the book I was looking for. It's the 14th book in the *[Necroscope](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40853-necroscope)* series.

[image: Front cover of "Necroscope: The Touch."]

> To test of the power of God, an insane triad of malevolent aliens decides to become so evil that God himself will have to stop them. They have already destroyed their homeworld, an entire solar system, and most of their own race. Their next target: Earth!
> In addition to advanced science mankind can only dream of, the Mordri Three have the unique ability to forever alter skin, bone, and muscle with a simple touch. Once this powerful touch was used only for healing, but the Mordri Three use it as a weapon, literally turning people inside out, mutating them in front of their horrified loved ones, or seeding them with cancer.
> Scott St. John is mourning the painful death of his beloved wife when he is struck by a golden arrow of light--a fragment of the soul of Harry Keogh, the original Necroscope--and gains powers he does not understand. Soon after, a mysterious, beautiful woman begins appearing everywhere he goes. She warns him to keep silent--about what, he does not know--and keeps trying to tell him something critically important, but each time, she vanishes before she can fully explain. And Scott begins to dream of a very unusual Wolf, who begs Scott--in human speech--to rescue him before the hunters come.
> A fledgling Necroscope, a telepathic Wolf, a beautiful woman from beyond the stars, the ghost of Harry Keogh, the best of E-Branch's psychic fighting forces, and a dead girl who is not yet ready to seek her just reward must defeat three impossibly strong, psychically gifted monsters whose touch literally melts flesh from bone.